# Sampling (Horvitz Thompson Estimation) Variance Estimation

Tags: estimation, bias, survey-sampling

If the second order inclusion probability is zero for any 2 units in the population, will the yates-grundy-sen variance estimator of the H-T estimator have infinite bias?

Comment: If $\pi_{ij} = 0$ for any $i, j., $ then the estimator will be negativity biased.